# Compaq Visual Fortran Install on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, fortran

Anyone successfully able to install Compaq Visual FORTRAN 6.x on Vista?

Tried the other day, but did not have any luck, so just wondering if obsolescence is upon this ol' compiler.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To answer the main question, and to follow to several comments.*

[Intel® Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-composer-xe-2011-release-notes/)'s support for Vista is officially depreciated, as of Update 3 of March 2011. Newer versions support Windows 7. Up until then, Vista was supported (and from what I hear, it still works, although I do not have it as my OS so cannot ascertain for that).

Compaq's Visual Fortran, which is "of the same line" as MS Fortran Powerstation, then Digital, then Compaqs and now Intel's, is no longer supported by any modern OS, although I can testify it works nice on XP SP3. Since it was discontinued *some time ago*, I would not expect it to work on either Vista or Win7 without some fiddling.

This only goes for the IDE part, the compiler in itself works okey.

If you wish to go into the process of trying to set it up, [these people's](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/2083-63-compaq-visual-fortran-64bit) experience may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that if you right click on the setup icon and click "Run as Administrator" then it works. Good luck. I am trying to find fortran for Vista still...

Comment: Cool.  I will be very interested to see what you find.  We have almost completed the port over to Intel FORTRAN, but are still unsure if it will install properly on Vista, but I am guessing probably not.

Comment: @Sahar - see my answer. Also, apart from Intel's there are other compilers for Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run a VM with whatever OS it was written for. Not the most elegant solution, but it's not like Vista is exactly the best operating system anyways. Have you ever considered upgrading to XP?